# How to set label color of livechart?

Tags: wpf, xaml, livecharts, material-design-in-xaml

I have an application based on materialdesigninxaml framework where I can set the light and the dark color, when the light color is setted I can see correctly the label text which is black, but when I set the dark theme the label of the charts still remain black, so I don't see anything. This is my chart:

```
 <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding}" LegendLocation="Bottom">
       <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
           <lvc:Axis Labels="{Binding AnalysisController.Labels}"/>
       </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
 </lvc:CartesianChart>
```

I tried to add this to my App.xaml as suggested by the documentation:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/LiveCharts.Wpf;component/Themes/Colors/white.xaml" />
```

but the color of the text is still black

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `Foreground` of your axis to another color like this:

```
<lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding}" LegendLocation="Bottom">
    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        <lvc:Axis Labels="{Binding AnalysisController.Labels}"
                  Foreground="White"/>
    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
</lvc:CartesianChart>
```